# Runtime and space complexity of the recursive determinant algorithm for a n x n matrix

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity, determinants

I am trying to figure out the runtime and space complexity of the algorithm below.

[image]

Some say that the runtime complexity of this is O(n!) and I am guessing it is because there are n! recursive calls for a recursive algorithm that solves for a n*n matrix. But I am not sure if I am right.

Also, is the space complexity also n!?

Comment: This question may be better suited to https://cs.stackexchange.com/ or even https://math.stackexchange.com/ (since it is about algorithms and complexity rather than programming).

Answer (score 0):

It might help to write out an explicit recurrence relation that governs the runtime of a straightforward implementation of the recursive algorithm. Notice that, in working on an n × n matrix, evaluating the sum requires making n recursive calls on matrices of size (n - 1) × (n - 1). Each recursive call requires about (n - 1)<sup>2</sup> additional time to set up, since we need to extract a submatrix of that size from the original matrix, so the total per-call overhead of the algorithm would be Θ(n<sup>3</sup>) because we’re doing quadratic work linearly many times. That means that our work done is roughly

> T(n) = nT(n - 1) + n<sup>3</sup>.

Completely ignoring the cubic term here, notice that expanding out the recursion will have the following effect:

> T(n) = nT(n - 1) + ...
>
> = n(n-1)T(n-2) + ...
>
> = n(n-1)(n-2)T(n-3) + ...

and eventually we’ll get an n! term showing up, plus a bunch of extra terms from the cubic. So the work done here is at least Ω(n!), and probably a lot more once we factor in the cubic term.

As for the space complexity - when working with the space complexity, remember that once one branch of the recursion terminates we can reuse the space that branch was using. This means that we only really need to look at any one branch to see how much space is needed.

With a naive implementation of this summation where we explicitly compute the submatrices for the recursive calls, we’ll need space to store one matrix of size n × n, one of size (n-1) × (n-1), one of size (n-2) × (n-2), etc. That space usage sums up to Θ(n<sup>3</sup>).

There are a bunch of other algorithms you can use to compute determinants in much less time and space. Some are based on Gaussian elimination and run in time O(n<sup>3</sup>), for example.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Sorry I still don't really understand why the space complexity is Θ(n3), you said the system only really needs enough storage for one branch at any given time. A branch should have n levels (n, n-1, n-2,...1). So then does that mean that each recursive call also needs storage space of n*n for a matrix. So then the total space needed is n levels times n*n amount of space needed for each level = n^3?

Comment: You do only need the storage space for one branch of the recursion. That would have n layers, and each layer needs about n^2 space to store the matrix associated with  that level. So yes, you need to scale everything by the space required for the new matrix it's creating.

Comment: Thank you! for the runtime complexity, do you know what its big O might be?

Comment: I mean, it's superexponential, so the practical answer is "don't compute things this way because it's at least n! operations." If you're interested in a theoretical answer, we can work one out together, but I doubt it will be useful. (I say this as someone who is a huge fan of math and theory, by the way!)